# SSIS Continue a complex dataflow from step 12

Tags: ssis

I have a complex Task flow that in general creates data warehouse content from Prod to a local DW server and then a copy of that to an offsite location.

Lately we keep failing in the copy to offsite.  Sure we moved offices and are getting these lines operation as expected.  Till then how do I get to run steps 12->20 and skip all of the first local steps?

TIA

Comment: My problem was that I was opening up the SSIS file and not putting it into a project.  When part of a project the rt click will show "run"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might make sense to to break steps out in seperate packages and invoke them in seperate steps perhaps in an agent job. In the immediate you can disable the steps 1-11 and then run the package